# how to touch and drag objects in a nsaaray

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to touch and move objects inside a nsarray as so. I can't figure out what to do next. Here is the code to show what I'm trying to do (Obviously doesn't work, but gives an idea). Perhaps someone can guide me.

```
     cardKeys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
            @"a",
            @"b",
            @"c",
            @"d",
                                 nil];

  -(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
   {

{
    UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];
  startPoint = [myTouch locationInView:self.view];

    [cardKeys:startPoint.x:startPoint.y];


}   


}
```

Comment: You just asked this like 2 hours ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334786/how-to-move-objects-around-in-xcode

Comment: Yes, but it wasn't clear. And actually the code and method of this is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is poorly formatted. Ex. extraneous pair of curly braces in the method, incorrect indentation. You should consider reading a good book on Objective-C and iOS development, like *Programming iOS 5*.

Onto your question. I have no idea how you display the NSStrings in that array, why it's global and not a property/ivar, etc. but one way to make something draggable is to make it a UIView subclass, implement touchesBegan and touchesMoved (as you have), grab the point the user touched in your coordinate system, compare it to the point the person's finger is when it moves, then offset your position based on that.

Comment: umm this isn't my whole code just some of it btw. So yes it would seem like that but it isn't.

Comment: If you post bits and pieces of your code, try to make sure the excerpts are well formatted outside of their original context. You'll also get more answers (and less downvotes) if you ask questions in a more precise manner. Ex. "I have an array of UIViews displayed on screen and I want to make it so that the user can drag them around." It's important that we know what kind of objects are in the array. Most people won't understand when you post code that defines an array of strings and you ask how you can "move them around." xD